# A sillcock with integrated manifold

Tags: plumbing, spigot

Like many, we have an exterior spigot with "garden hose" threads on it. Like many, we find a single spigot not enough and attach a manifold to it.

Unfortunately, those manifolds -- be they made of brass or plastic -- are flimsy and last no more than two seasons. Simpler dual ones are more reliable than quads, but aren't good either. And I don't mean just that the seals start leaking (though that's annoying too), water begins to drip from the inside too. Amazon's ratings for these implements rarely rise over 4...

Which leads me to the thought of replacing the very spigot with something having a *built-in* manifold. I cannot find such a thing readily-made online -- maybe, I can create one myself and replace my current with it?

How would I do it -- to survive winters -- and why hasn't anyone thought of offering such a thing commercially (or, at least, marketing it widely enough for Google to find it)?

Comment: i just buy cheap brass ones and consider a 2nd summer a bonus.

Comment: I disassemble everything in the fall, and replace the connection washers from time to time.

Comment: I have up to 5 with each one having a ball valve, this is at a barn but I removed the standard faucet installed a T you could do the same but where I added additional T’s you can use an elbow nipple spigot or a ball valve (I used ball valves) and another nipple (I did everything in 3/4” so the last nipple connects to a hose fine, you could do it in half inch and adapt to 3/4 after the valve I did wrap them with neoprene pipe insulation as it freezes hard enough to break the valves or pipes , I also have a 3 way one at the other end of the barn this has lasted 5 years so far.

Comment: So you replaced the old sillcock with something else, @EdBeal? Wish I could find a sillcock with either smooth end (for sharkbite to attach), or with real (permanent) threads. But they all seem to come with "garden hose" threads instead :(

Comment: The fitting my spigot / frost free screwed in to was 3/4 npt most pipe thread in homes is 1/2 or 3/4  I brought the nipple out t then nipple’s or 90’s to ball valves , I have done this at my last home and have similar in my barn now. Horses tend to be rough on plumbing so each stall has valves I used to use the brass hose connectors/ splitters but after years of leaks and broken / having to replace tried my own and it cost more up front but no leaks and many years later they still work , never had even high dollar brass ones last very long.

Answer (score 3):

**Drill 3 more holes in the wall and insert and plumb 3 more sillcocks.** If it helps, put them not all next to each other (distribute them around the house close to where you use hoses,) but if you need them all in one place, line them up next to each other.

Or even dig a trench and put one or more frost free hydrants *out in the yard.*

Or: attach one quick connect to the faucet and 4 (or more) mating quick connects to your 4 (or more) hoses, so you can easily attach the hose you are actually using. Unfortunately those are subject to failure as well. Then again, so are hoses.

I have two sillcocks at present, one at front, one at back, and if I find use for another I'll happily add it.

Comment: Thank you, this is *so much* the answer!  Sillcocks are *special* and do not like manifolds (or even hoses) left attached to them with a closed valve past them.  They need their innards to gravity-drain every time they are shut off.

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the manifold over the winter (if you don't already).

Also, consider purchasing a short stretch of hose that will reach from the silcock to the ground, install the manifold on the end of the hose then install the other hoses here. That would remove the stress of the hoses (full of water) hanging on the manifold and likely help it last longer.

Finally, do you need/use all those hoses all at the same time? Is it worth the trouble/expense to replace the manifold vs dragging one hose to different areas of your yard vs having several hoses pre-set and connecting the one that you need to use when you need to use it? After all, you're going to be at the silcock to turn the water on, you could take another minute to attach the correct hose and avoid the problem all together.